# Question about Wix Domain and IIS Windows Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'll use fake domain names as an example, I have a web app working in IIS on a VPS (app.myapp.com) It's a subdomain from myapp.com, but I want to change the domain, I've brought one on WIX called newapp.com, I can't use newapp.com because is already used for a Web site, so I created a subdomain called app.newapp.com in DNS management in Wix but in IIS I've changed the bindings and also I created DNS rules, but It didn't work.

Comment: So what does `nslookup app.newapp.com` return at terminal/command prompt?

Comment: Can you use command line to pin app.newapp.com? What do you mean "It didn't work"? Can you describe more detailed about issue? For example error page, error message.